# Are there parts of text missing in published errata?

Tags: dnd-4e

Browsing through [the latest errata of DnD4](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive) (first PDF in the list as of now, dated 11/09/2011), I stumbled upon multiple entries that are missing essential parts.
For example, in the item for the *prone* condition (p21), a bullet point is mentioned which is to be replaced by an allegedly following bullet point. But that bullet point does not exist.

Or this one:

> *Stalker’s Armor* (Page 53): Replace the item’s property. This change 
>   prevents the property from being recursive.

Replace with what?

I find a similar issue with *Impenetrable Barding*, *Crown of Infernal Legacy* and *Phrenic Crown*. That's three times on just one page, out of 113. Can't be simply an error, can it?

Am I missing something here? Is there another source where those missing parts are to be found?

Comment: That list is describing the errata, but is not telling you what the errata actually is. I can't remember where to find the actual errata? Maybe only if you have DDI?

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your question. I think the meaning is untouched, fwiw.

Comment: I also edited in the link to the errata files. They are available without a DDI subscription.

Comment: I meant that the complete new text for any given power may only be available with a DDI

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything missing. The text is purely descriptive. The trick here is that the descriptive text describes the text as it is now composed.

Sometimes the errata will give you the text that is superseded, but most of the time if you want to see the old text you have to look it up where it was published.

The notification of errata in the compendium merely serves to let you know that the text in the book is wrong and should be replaced by the text in the compendium. This is the prevent confusion and to help players know when things have been changed.

Comment: I think the point is, that with the errata files alone, you can't update your books with little sticky notes for the correct text. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: If a rule was updated twice, you'd have to track all previous changes to the new text. Plus, some stuff in the errata document does contain the complete replacement text, like *"Spiritlink Armor
Page 53: In the item’s property, replace “Level 24” 
with “Level 25,” and replace “Level 29” with “Level 
30.”"*

Answer (score 1):

The text for the "Prone" condition update reads:

> *Prone Page 277*: Replace the bullet point that reads “You’re  lying on
> the ground. (If you’re f lying, you safely  descend a distance equal
> to your f ly speed. If you  don’t reach the ground, you fall.)” with
> the following  bullet point.

Indeed, there's no following bullet point. The next item is *Restrained*, on the following page.

As for the *"Stalker's Armor"* case, the Compendium states:

> **Property**
>
> Whenever you have concealment at the start of your turn from a source
> other than this armor, you remain concealed until the start of your
> next turn.

I can't say if this is the original text or it's already updated. The errata doesn't make sense to me for this text. The situation is similar for the next three items you mention. Perhaps someone with the original Adventurer's Vault can clarify this.

Comment: Original text: "When you have concealment from a creture at teh start of your turn, you remain concealed from that creature until the start of your next turn." In other words you would have perpetual concealment.

Comment: So, the errata text is indeed incomplete, as @lostinnovelty says.

Comment: I don't think so, not on this particular one. It merely mentions that it prevents the property from becoming recursive, which it does. No need to get further into the details.

Comment: @wax eagle If the errata only says "Replace the item’s property. This change prevents the property from being recursive.", what would you replace it with? if "with the new compendium text", how do I get from a public document to the login-required compendium? The replacement text should be in the errata.